# R - TraMineR rotate ytlab

Tags: r, axis-labels, traminer

I wanted to know if it was possible to rotate the `ytlab` in a `seqIplot` in `TraMineR`. I also get a warning message when I try to use the `row.names` of the sequence.

The data :

```
mc = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0,     0,     0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(10L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("d Travel/Commute", "j Care for others", "r Religious", 
    "u Others", "e Cooking", "f Housework", "h Eating", "l Leisure", 
    "t TV/Radio", "o Telephone/Online Communication"), c("V1", 
    "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5")))
```

The sequence

```
sq = seqdef(mc, cpal =  heat.colors(3))
```

The `Iplot`

```
seqIplot(sq, border = NA, ytlab = attributes(sq)$row.names, las = 2)
```

the `las = 2` argument is apparently not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `axis()` to specify on which axis `las` applies.

Also you need to specify the points at which you want the tick marks. The `seqIplot` uses a 0-1 scale and makes some adjustment at the start. Moreover, to rotate the labels, you have to spare some place with `par(mar=...)`.

Here is how you can get rotated labels for your example:

```
step = nrow(mc)+3
par(mar=c(5,20,2,2))
seqIplot(sq, border = NA, ylab=NA, ytlab=FALSE)
axis(2, at=2.15/step + 1:10*(1/step), labels=rownames(sq), las = 2)
```

Hope this helps.